# Excel workbook translation using Google API

Tags: python, excel, vba, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I want to translate all the text in Excel worksheet(Sheet1) into English using Google API and save it in another worksheet(Sheet2).

The method using Python works well, but I should use Excel vba due to user environment.

However, I don't know about VBA, so I want to get help with VBA CODE to solve this problem.

[image: MY DATA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by working in python pandas and outputting it as an excel file.

Answer (score 1):

There might be more than one solution for this problem. You could simply import your Excel sheet to Google Sheets and use [Google Sheets Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) to solve mentioned issue. In particular, it may be worthwhile having a look at [GOOGLETRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en) function.